# How to enhance the performance of bitmap texture rendering in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to revive an old game using cocos2dx.
What I have done was reading the legacy binary files and extract the bitmap files ,and there is total 68k of bitmap files inside it.
So for now I have already read the file, decompress the bytes, transform the bitmap from RGB8 to RGBA8888, and then generate the bitmap as texture and creating a sprite.
But since it was an isometric game, so there is a map and consists of many tiles. So drawing the map with different textures (each bitmap as a individual texture) costs a lot of glcalls. What I have done is trying to reuse the texture and group them by local zorder to try to make use of the auto batching.

And for the animation of a character, now I have created 127 individual bitmap textures and try to create sprite frame on it one by one.

After all of the works the gl draw calls reduce from 800 to 50. But unluckyly the FPS is still too slow (drops to 10-20 and it should be 60)

The tests are ran on the iphone simulator, although it does not have any GPU, but is this still a normal FPS?(with almost 13k gl verts)

And does the FPS affected by the number of the textures of my character animation?

Should I try to pack the textures at the runtime? e.g. combine the textures to make a bigger texture in memory in runtime and loading them by offsets.

Comment: what did you really mean by gl calls? what did it have an effect on FPS? do you also call glTexImage2D() every frame?

Comment: It is the debug messages by cocos2dx, so what I understand should be gl draw calls? And the fps should be quite related to the gl draw calls or no? And I haven't really use the opengl calls directly, I left it all to the cocos2dx engine to do so. So do you suggest that I should go into opengl routine instead of using cocos2dx?

Comment: Do you actually know what your bottleneck is? 50 draw calls and 13K verts is nothing, so it doesn't sound like the OpenGL layer is actually your problem. Have you tried profiling your application? What device GPU are you using?

Comment: I think your question is not specific. how slow FPS is slow and on what device? On old iphones, 50 drawcall with 13k could be a huge work. Use VBO not to call glvertxxx every time but it might not help you to solve the main problem. Do you use any expensive shader code?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, and I have edited the questions to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even look at performance on the simulator. It's completely irrelevant and non-representative.

All current iOS devices will cope with 50 draw calls and 13k verts just fine, unless you have some other bottleneck (which you'll only find out by running on device), then you'll be running at 60fps for sure.